# Создание SSL сертификата

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, ssl

Использую бота телеграм который связан с веб приложением. Бот и приложение крутятся на сервере, у меня есть только белый IP

Для корректной работы необходимо чтобы взаимодействие было по https. Сделал самоподписанный SSL сертификат (тк есть только ip не могу воспользоваться сервисами по типу lets encrypt). Но ничего не работает, как можно решить эту проблему. Читал, что можно отправить открытый ключ сертификата телеге, делаю это вот так:

```
curl -F "url=https://айпи_моего_сервера" -F "certificate=@имя_сертификата.pem" "https://api.telegram.org/токен_бота/setwebhook"
```

В ответ получаю:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}
```

Подскажите как можно решить эту задачу

Comment: урл точно не регистрозависимы? set**W**ebhook, ну и второе - нужен домен :) с айпи - не работает

Comment: Анатолий, могу Вам совершенно бесплатно и без смс сделать домен третьего уровня в своём домене junecat.ru. тогда у Вас нормально сработает L.E. - сертификат. Давайте IP в телеграмм :-)

Comment: @S.H. для подобных задач можно и каким-нибудь .tk ограничиться

Comment: Да, домен третьего уровня можно и без моей помощи зарегистрировать.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, а в чем разница?

Comment: Понятия не имею, если вы про регистр - сервера могут быть настроены на обработку урл с учетом регистра и без оного. про домен - это требование телеграмма а не мое, и описано одним из первых в возможных причинах неработоспособности.